# android: cast a method dynamically at runtime

Tags: android, casting, android-activity

Given the code:

```
public class CommandSequence {

public CommandSequence() {
}

public void startCommunications(View v) {
    Bundle dataout1 = new Bundle();
    dataout1.putInt("ACTION", Communications.ACTION_LOAD_COMMAND_ONLY);
    dataout1.putInt("PORT", Commands.MESSAGE_TYPE_SMC);
    dataout1.putInt("COMMAND", Commands.SMC_RESETEVENTSTATUS);
    ((MainActivity) v.getContext()).sendMessageToBackgroundCommunicationsService(
        Communications.MESSAGE_LOAD_COMMAND,
        dataout1);
}
}
```

I must cast 'sendMessageToBackgroundCommunicationsService()' with the calling activity context, which is 'MainActivity'.

Is it possible to pass a parameter that will allow me to cast the method call at runtime, so that this method can be called from any activity class?

Comment: I basically will take the advisement David Hirst's first answer. I will only call this class from MainActivity and the casts will remain in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a base activity class that all your activies inherit and then cast to this instead when you need to make a call:

```
((MyBaseActivity) v.getContext()).sendMessageToBackgroundCommunicationsService(
    Communications.MESSAGE_LOAD_COMMAND,
    dataout1);
```

[EDIT] In fact to make your code a bit better you could pass the activity into your method so there is no dependency on your class needing to know another class.

```
public void startCommunications(View v, Class myActivity) {
 //your code
}
```